# Determine points of tangency (Putnam 2007)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, contest-math

> Find all values of $ \alpha$ for which the curves $ y=\alpha x^2+\alpha x+\frac1{24}$ and $ x=\alpha y^2+\alpha y+\frac1{24}$ are tangent to each other.

This is an old Putnam Problem (2007 A1)

Obviously,

$$y' = 2\alpha x + \alpha$$

And

$$1 = 2\alpha y y' + \alpha y' \implies y' = \frac{1}{2\alpha y + \alpha}$$

Letting them equal.

$$2\alpha x + \alpha = \frac{1}{2\alpha y + \alpha}$$

$$\implies \alpha(2x + 1) = \frac{1}{\alpha(2y  + 1)} \implies \alpha^2 (2x + 1)(2y + 1) = 1$$

bUt  I cant do much =(

Comment: Generally, http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/ has discussions of all old Putnam questions.

Comment: I imagine you will find [this](http://kskedlaya.org/putnam-archive/) to be *quite* helpful.

Comment: You can find a solution for example here : https://people.math.osu.edu/derdzinski.1/courses/1187/Solutions-Putnam-2007.pdf, here : http://inside.mines.edu/~dlarue/putnam/exams/2007s.pdf, here : http://www.math.ksu.edu/~nagy/putnam/sol2007a1.pdf...